# mysql need complete count of a column and group by some columns

Tags: mysql, count

I need a complete count of each person_id from the database according to the date wise report

```
SELECT date, person_id, count(person_id) 
FROM visits 
group by date, person_id
```

I tried this one but this couldn't give the result what I expected.

```
 Date           |   person_id|  count(person_id)
2018-01-01      |     33000  |      10       |
2018-01-01      |    712000  |      111      |
2018-01-01      |    730000  |      30       |
2018-01-01      |    743000  |      5        |
2018-01-01      |    755000  |      123      |
```

Comment: Also you haven't said what you actually want the query to return.

Comment: Cool story bro. Just posting a status report? Or was there a question?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

you need `total` append to your query result? For example:

```
Date           |   person_id|  count(person_id) | total
2018-01-01     |     33000  |      10           | 1000
2018-01-01     |    712000  |      111          | 1000
```

right? if so, I don't think it's a good idea only using sql query. On my case, I will query twice asynchronously，and then merge the result.

like this:

query1:

```
SELECT date, person_id, count(person_id) 
FROM visits 
group by date, person_id
```

query2:

```
SELECT count(person_id) as total
FROM visits
```

and then merge the results by program.

Comment: I think it's more like they want a total per person_id, not a total of all person_ids. "I need a complete count of each person_id". So more like `SELECT person_id, count(person_id) as total_per_person
FROM visits GROUP BY person_id`. Or, if it is what you are suggesting, where they want a total count of all person_ids, it should be `SELECT count(DISTINCT person_id) as total_persons
FROM visits`. Otherwise, if all they need is the total visits (eg the row count for the visits table), they could just do `SELECT count(1) as total_visits FROM visits`.